# How to raise an exception when a list contains negative values

Tags: python, list, for-loop, if-statement, negative-number

I want calculate the harmonic mean and raise an exception if my list "x" contains negative values.
But the code is not working. How can I adjust my **for + if statemen**t to fix the problem?
Thanks.

```
x=[1,2,3.0,-3,,-2,1]

def hmean(x):
  sum= 0.0
  for i in x:
    if i < 0:
      raise Exception("list contains negative values")
    else:
      sum = 0.0
      for i in x:
        sum+= 1.0 / i
      return print(float(len(x) / sum))
```

Comment: unindent the `return`, it should have the same indent level as the `for` statement. also you shouldn't combine `return` and `print` like that, just stick to `return` in this case

Comment: `sum` is a python function u cant use it as a variable name.

Comment: what is your output?

Comment: @CC7052: You ***can*** use it as a variable name, but you won't be call to use the built-in function `sum()` afterwards if you do.

Comment: hblanc28: I suggest you get your code working on lists that don't have negative values first, then add a check for those afterwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several problems with this code:

```
def hmean(x):
  for i in x:
    if i < 0:
      raise Exception("list contains negative values")
  # no need for else:, we come here if exception is not raised
  s = 0.0 # do not use sum as variable name
  for i in x:
    s += 1.0 / i
  return float(len(x)) / s # return needs to be outside the for loop; also, no print() here
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi if you want to correct your answer think it will help:

```
x=[1,2,3.0,-3,2,-2,1]

def hmean(x):
    s= 0.0
    for i in x:
        if i < 0:
            raise Exception("list contains negative values")
        else:

            s += 1.0 / i
    return float(len(x) / sum)
hm = hmean(x)
print(hm)
```